# Common way to put delete "x" link for tag input

Tags: best-practice, tags, delete, tagging, metaphor

Does anybody know why it is a common way to put "x" link to delete a tag on the right side of the tag?

[image]

I got an opinion which makes sense, that  placing "x" on the left could help with quick removal of multiple tags, because you could just click without moving a mouse cursor, whilst new tags will fall into place of previously deleted tag.

Comment: Just want to add that your benefit of being able to delete multiple tags quickly without having to move your mouse, is also a downside because if you accidentaly double click you're going to unintentionally delete a tag. (less friction isn't always a good thing, especially in irreverable actions)

Answer (score 1):

What you have suggested is good and many of them have also tried but how ever it got used as much as we using on "X"right side.
Its because of traditional culture we followed for a long period of time by using the format "left to right culture".

Hope this link will give you more about the alignment "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment".